# Segmentation faults in the code

Tags: c

I keep getting segmentation faults but i have no clue why, i figured out where my segmentation fault was but dont know how to fix it.

```
struct node {
        int line;
        int count;
        char* word;
        struct node* next;
};

struct node* nodeGetPreviousNode (struct node* head, struct node* node)
{
        //return the previous node given the node
        while(((head) != NULL) ||((head)->next != node))
        {
                (head) = (head)->next;
        }
        return (head);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
while(((head) != NULL) ||((head)->next != node))
```

will evaluate `(head)->next != node`, dereferencing `head` when `head` is `NULL`

Did you mean to use `&&` instead?

Comment: True, I'm not sure how C evaluates but things to the right of || can only ever not be evaluated if the first is `true`--first being `false` is not enough to conclude whether the expression as a whole is `true` or `false`.

Comment: @j.i.h. The && and || operators are guaranteed to fully evaluate the left operand before the right one.

Comment: Right, that's what I was trying to point out for the uninitiated (the short-circuiting).